# 「メタ」という言葉が解りづらい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, 専門用語

スタックオーバーフローの運営を議論する場に「メタ」がありますが、「メタ」という言葉が解りづらいです。「運営フォーラム」等、日本人に馴染みやすい言葉はないでしょうか？

以下の記述を見た時に、何の事を言っているのか分かりませんでした。

- メタでのおすすめ
- このサイトの疑問点・改善点をメタで教えてください！
- メタ投稿

リンクをクリックしてメタサイトに来た時、何が起こっているのか分からず混乱した覚えもあります。

Comment: 分かりづらいため、ヘルプ記事まで作っています：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta　（もちろん改善案は大歓迎です。追加情報を共有しようと思いました）

Comment: @jmac ヘルプ記事全般に言えますが、ヘルプ記事への導線が少ない（もしくは目立たない）ように感じます。誰かに案内されるか、自分で探検にでも行かないと記事の存在にすら気付かないのでは？

Comment: @unarist 基本的に、登録されたユーザーの１割しかメタに参加しないです。残りの９割はプログラミングのQ&Aに集中したいであれば、メタの説明に時間を撮りたくないです。代わりに、メタに初めて尋ねた方に何かの説明メッセージを出しましょうか？（できるかどうかは別ですが、確認はできます）

Comment: メタの利用者が少ないとは思うのですが、全てのユーザに「メタでのおすすめ」「今話題のメタ投稿」が表示されているかと思います。この下当たりに、「メタとは何？」といったヘルプへのリンクを付けてはいかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 8):

「メタ(meta)」があまり一般的な用語ではないことは認めつつも、ここスタック・オーバーフローというサイト固有の専門用語として、**現状維持**（メタのまま）に1票入れます。

[プログラマー向けのサイト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)という専門性・特殊性もありますし、利用者層にとっては決して馴染みの薄い単語ではないと思います。

Comment: 私もプログラマなんですが、「メタで教えて下さい」を最初に見た時は、何か特別なメタ言語でもあるのかと思ってしまいました。

Comment: 何か特別なメタ言語～と思われたのであれば、"メタ"について正しく認識されて居られますよね :P

Answer (score 3):

スタックオーバーフロー自身について話したり質問できる場、ということでの meta なので、運営やサポートと言ってしまうのはなんだか仰々しい気がします。

[C'Mon Get Meta! – Stack Exchange Blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/)

知恵袋は・・・と見てみると、[Yahoo!知恵袋カテゴリ](http://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/dir/list/d2078297310/solved)があるようです。

---

> 以下の記述を見た時に、何の事を言っているのか分かりませんでした。

あまりにも知らない言葉だらけでは使い始めるのに抵抗があるかもしれませんが、そのような感覚自体は、逆に関心を持ってもらうきっかけにもなると思います。

どんな名前を付けたところで、それが伝わらない場合はあります。そういう意味では、

> リンクをクリックしてメタサイトに来た時、何が起こっているのか分からず混乱した覚えもあります。

こっちの方が問題かなという気がします。メインとメタの画面が似ていて紛らわしいとか。

「承認」や「お礼」もそうですけど、独特な機能が多いわりに説明が少ないかもなーとは思います。

---

「説明しなくてもわかる」というのは裏を返せば、実際と異なる先入観を与える可能性があるということです。わかりやすくはなるかもしれませんが、逆に運営やサポートという表現を使って敷居の高そうな印象を与えてしまうかもと思うと、「是非変えよう！」とは思わない、というところです。

Comment: もし、説明しなくても、分かるように出来る物があるのなら、１つ１つその努力を積み上げて貢献したいです。